# Proof that $f'(0)$ of an even function is always $0$.

Tags: functions, derivatives, proof-verification

$f \in C^1$ and "even" meaning that $\forall x:f(x)=f(-x)$. To me it seems logical, but I'm struggling with writing it down. Does this work?

$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\lim_{-2x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(-x)-f(x)}{-2x}=0$$

It reeks, but perhaps it can be salvaged (unless there are some extreme counterexamples).

Comment: You cannot presume that $h$ and $2x$ approach $0$ in the same way.

Comment: @corindo Can I define $h:=-2x?$

Comment: But $x$ is fixed when you evaluate $\lim_{h\to 0}$.

Comment: @JohnMa That's game over for my proof then

Comment: I guess so, I am not sure if $f\in C^1$ can in any way help you say something similar. @Grantwalzer .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof does not work, as $h$ and $x$ tend to $0$ independently. Instead, differentiate both sides of the equation $f(x) = f(-x)$, using the chain rule on the right hand side. You get $f'(x) = -f'(-x)$. Then $f'(0) = -f'(0)$, which implies $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: $f'(x)\neq f'(-x)$ (!)...

Comment: That's not what I had. I wrote $f'(x) = - f'(-x)$.

Comment: I know^^—it's what I oversaw while thinking about it :\

Comment: Oh I see, understood. :)

Answer (score 2):

The following does not use the fact that $f$ is $C^1$. We assume only that $f$ is even and $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

Hint: Note that

$$\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = - \ \frac{f(-h) - f(0)}{(-h)}. $$

Now recall that a limit exist if and only if both the left hand and right hand limit exists **and are equal**.